# Calculated number of consecutive High values in sas

Tags: sas

```
data bob;
input subjid test$ lbdy flag1$;
datalines;

101 alt 1 e
101 alt 2 .
101 alt 3 e
101 alt 4 e
101 ast 1 e
101 ast 3 e
101 ast 4 .
101 ast 5 e
102 alt 1 e
102 alt 2 .
102 alt 3 e
102 alt 4 e
102 ast 1 e
102 ast 2 .
102 ast 3 e
102 ast 4 .
102 ast 5 e
102 ast 6 e
;
run;
```

I need to find the consecutive value

My expected output is

```
             count
101 alt 1 e   1
101 alt 2 .   
101 alt 3 e   2
101 alt 4 e   2
101 ast 1 e   2
101 ast 3 e   2
101 ast 4 .
101 ast 5 e   1 
102 alt 1 e   4
102 alt 2 e   4
102 alt 3 e   4
102 alt 4 e   4
102 ast 1 e   1
102 ast 2 .   
102 ast 3 e   1
102 ast 4 .
102 ast 5 e   2
102 ast 6 e   2
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: What value do you need to find consecutively? What is considered 'high?' It clearly has something to do with Flag1 `e`, but I do not see any pattern with consecutively high values. Please clarify your question.

Comment: I need to count the 'e' based on the day, if we have a missing then we need to start the count again from 1... @stuSZtukowski

Comment: Your variables are `SubjectID`, `Test`, `Lbdy`, `Flag1`, but there is no `day` variable. When does `count` increment?

Comment: day variable is LBDY only @stuSZtukowski

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I reckon this is what you want.  Hard to know from cryptic description.

```
data bob;
input subjid test$ lbdy flag1$;
datalines;
101 alt 1 e
101 alt 2 .
101 alt 3 e
101 alt 4 e
101 ast 1 e
101 ast 3 e
101 ast 4 .
101 ast 5 e
102 alt 1 e
102 alt 2 e
102 alt 3 e
102 alt 4 e
102 ast 1 e
102 ast 2 .
102 ast 3 e
102 ast 4 .
102 ast 5 e
102 ast 6 e
;;;;
   run;
proc sort data=bob;
   by subjid test lbdy;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
data dob2;
   do _n_=1 by 1 until(last.flag1);
      set bob;
      by subjid test flag1 notsorted;
      end;
   if not missing(flag1) then count = _n_;
   do _n_ = 1 to _n_;
      set bob;
      output;
      end;
   run;
proc print;
   run;
```

[image]